# What character growth happens beyond level 20?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-advancement

Level 20 is shown to be the level **cap**. So does getting 30000 XP for the epic boons or added ability scores implement into character's statistics such as max prepared spells or max health increase?

For example a 20th level Wizard with 20 intelligence can prepare a maximum of 25 spells. 
After gaining 30000 XP would that wizard be considered level 21 and get 26 maximum spells?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### The 20th level is the highest you can achieve.

Per the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, p. 38 (["Levels 17-20: Masters of the World"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/creating-a-campaign#Levels1720MastersoftheWorld)):

> Characters who reach 20th level have attained the pinnacle of mortal achievement. Their deeds are recorded in the annals of history and recounted by bards for centuries

However you can still get more powerful. You may get an epic boon for every 30,000 XP you earn above 355,000 XP, if the DM follows the suggestion in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (p. 231).

Epic boons offer a variety of things, including: immortality, truesight, nullifying damage, extra hit points, spell slots, and much more.

Answer (score 16):

### No. Level 20 is the highest level.

As you said: 20 is the highest level described in the PHB, and XP gains beyond 355,000 are described in DMG Chapter 7 as gaining one other advancements, not levels. There is no WotC "Tier of Play" beyond level 20.

However, you're not alone in looking for higher-level play options. There's nothing stopping you and your table from designing the progression you'd envision from higher levels and you'd be joining a long history of those who have done so<sup>1</sup> Just understand that you're intentionally moving away from the design principles<sup>2</sup> of 5e when doing so.

---

<sup>1 - See Skip Williams' *High-Level Campaigns* for 2e, for example; in my experience 2e's been a pretty good go-to for supplementing 5e. Examples here: [[1]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/69010/23970), [[2]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/71143/23970), [[3]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/72209/23970).</sup>

<sup>2- "The basic premise behind the bounded accuracy system is simple: we make no assumptions on the DM’s side of the game that the player’s attack and spell accuracy, or their defenses, increase as a result of gaining levels. Instead, we represent the difference in characters of various levels primarily through their hit points, the amount of damage they deal, and the various new abilities they have gained. Characters can fight tougher monsters not because they can finally hit them, but because their damage is sufficient to take a significant chunk out of the monster’s hit points; likewise, the character can now stand up to a few hits from that monster without being killed easily, thanks to the character’s increased hit points. Furthermore, gaining levels grants the characters new capabilities, which go much farther toward making your character feel different than simple numerical increases." Rodney Thompson, *Legends and Lore*, quoted in ["Under the Hood--Bounded Accuracy"](http://roleplayerschronicle.com/?p=22767) at roleplayeschronicle.com. Wizards.com has apparently lost many recent *L&L* articles, and any references to them seem to be broken links.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

### Epic Boons are the only advancement past 20.

As you have observed, the rules for [Beyond 1st Level](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/step-by-step-characters#Beyond1stLevel) do not permit advancement past 20th level. That is, while this section does not contain a statement like “20th is the max level”, all the rules contained therein provide for advancing as high as 20th, *and no further*. Instead, the *Dungeon Master’s Guide* contains rules for advancement past 20th level in the form of Epic Boons:

> An epic boon is a special power available only to 20th level characters. […]
>
> Epic boons can also be used as a form of advancement, a way to provide greater power to characters who have **no more levels to gain**. With this approach, consider awarding one epic boon to each character for every 30,000 XP he or she earns above 355,000 XP.

Notably, this section does positively confirm that a 20th level character has “no more levels to gain”. The only thing gained with an Epic Boon is the Epic Boom itself. Class features that reference your level will always use 20, never higher.

Comment: (Posting a new answer because it provides a more direct confirmation that 20th is the max level)